# Composite relationship in RESTful API using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

What would be recommended way to implement composite relationship between two entities when building REST API using Spring Boot and Spring Data JPA?

As we have existence dependency between container and its contents, do we have to create, update and delete contents through container's API, or should it be handled through separate, specific content's API call?

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, this doesn't depend on the chosen framework (eg Spring) but depends on the chosen architecture.

If you, for example, adhere to [DDD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design) principles and your entities compose an [aggregate](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/DDD_Aggregate.html), then you should work with them as a [single whole](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-persisting-ddd-aggregates).

Otherwise, if they are independent, you can work with them separately.